# Как использовать ИИ для "поиска" артиста и названия песни в строке?

Tags: python, keras, искусственный-интеллект

К примеру получая с названия видео в ютуба, зачастую каша с тегами, много лишнего текста. Как в такой строке с помощью ИИ найти именно имя артиста и название песни.

Давать ИИ на вход одну строку с текстом, а на выходе получить артиста и название песни. В попытках я попробовал составить датасет, используя три столбца, сплошной текст и два столбца с правильными  данными соответственно. Как лучше реализовать обучение такой сети, не смог разобраться.

Добавляю.
На входе строка с названия видео. На выходе название песни и имя артиста.

```
Вход: `Lontalius - sleep thru ur alarm's | Extended Version | XBeats`
Выход1: `Lontalius`
Выход2: `sleep thru ur alarm's`
```

[Датасет ~140](https://dropmefiles.com.ua/ua/EUXzSVf5)

Comment: Для начала - конкретизируйте свое ТЗ. Что же именно у вас на входе, и что вы хотите получить на выходе. Далее соберите данные с примерами, на которых будете работать, штук 200 например.

Comment: Так то это что-то близкое к NER, но вообще не уверен, как к этой задаче лучше подходить. В любом случае сначала нужно собрать хоть какие-то данные, да.